# Can I use a redis set as an argument in MGET?

Tags: redis

If I have a set containing a list of keys, can I then use that set as an argument in MGET to get all the keys named in the set? I'm more interested in a method that doesn't involve EVAL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, MGET isn't an option here but [`SORT`](http://redis.io/commands/sort) is.

Assuming a list called `foo` whose members are key names in the database, you can use the following to return the keys' values rather than the list's contents:

```
SORT foo BY nosort GET *
```